# Is shear elasticity the same as shear modulus?

Tags: terminology, material-science, elasticity, stress-strain

I've encountered both the terms "shear elasticity" and ["shear modulus"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_modulus). Are these the same?

Answer (score 1):

Shear Elasticity and Shear modulas (also called modulas of rigidity) are same. For details, use these links:

1. [Shear Elasticity](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ElasticityOfShear/)
2. [Shear modulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_modulus)